# Wordpress favicon hack

Tags: wordpress, favicon

A wordpress site of mine got hacked and there appears to be a favicon left by the hacker.

I cannot see it anywhere in the theme, there is no shortcut line in the header

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/favicon.ico" />
```

Any ideas where this file can be?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to caching. You have to refresh it to remove the old icon.

Locate the favicon resource of your site by navigating to `<YOUR SITE URL>/favicon.ico` in your browser and do a hard refresh.

If the above doesn't work, try setting a new favicon by adding this to your current theme's `header.php` file.

`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/favicon.ico?ver=new" />` and upload the new favicon to the appropriate location.